# Running tests for modules inside a crate

Tags: testing, rust

I'm writing a crate which consists of multiple modules spread across multiple files. These modules are interdependent, i.e. some of the modules use other modules inside this crate.

Is it possible to run tests in such modules separately from other modules in the crate? Running `rust test some_module.rs` does not work if `some_module.rs` contains references to other modules in this crate. Running `rust test my_crate.rc` does work, but it runs tests from all of crate modules, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to run a subset of the tests:

```
> rustc --test my_crate.rc
> ./my_crate some_module

... test output ...
```

This will run any function for which the full path contains `some_module`. There is a [fairly detailed help page for unit testing](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/wiki/Doc-unit-testing) on the wiki, including [this use case](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/wiki/Doc-unit-testing#running-a-subset-of-tests).

Note that `rust test` doesn't support this (yet!), so you have to compile the test runner and invoke it by hand (or, write a Makefile/script to do it).

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to work. It would be great if `rust` tool supported something like this though.

Comment: Certainly would be! The `rust` tool is very incomplete at the moment.